# How to import formula into picklist text field

Tags: smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I have a symbol picklist using the colored circles, but it uses a formula to conditionally pick the right choice based on other cell values.

If I try to import the formula using the API, I get an error that it's an invalid value based on the picklist (should be "Red", "Green", etc.).  The formula in the sheet itself works fine, when entered manually.

How can I get the formula to be imported and used in the sheet?
Would it be a modification to the cell build function - such as defining it as a formula?:

```
new Cell.AddCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[0].Id, trafficLight).Build()
```

FYI - I need to re-add the formula for each row because I'm deleting all rows and re-adding each time the import runs.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, according to Smartsheet's documentation, formulas cannot be imported into Smartsheet via the API.